# Create var's automatically from json key,value pairs for global use

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

> update: i remembered that i can store them as
>   jQuery(document).data(key,value); for later use, but is this a good
>   idea ? Would that be an expensive option performance-wise ?

I am trying to create var's automatically from a json array key,value pairs for later use.

So i basically created two sets of settings, 1- Default Settings (defSets) 2- User Settings (usrSets). The idea is to use user setting if it exists, otherwise fallback to default setting.
I do not want to write in all vars one by one, so is there a way to create global vars from these arrays for later use in various places ?

sth along the lines like:
`var [key_name] = [key_value_read_from_User_Setting_or_Default_Set];`

Here is my actual code below; the problem is, it seems to create the vars within the each loop, but i cant access them globally i think.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
// read default settings array from cookie if exist, otherwise create initial default settings and save
  if (jQuery.cookie("defSets") != null) {
    var defSets = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.cookie("defSets"))
  } else {
    var defSets = { 'ord': 'true', 'itemc': 4, 'ratio': 'sq', 'sortby': 'def'};
    jQuery.cookie("defSets", JSON.stringify(defSets)); 
  };
  // read user settings array from cookie if exist, otherwise create initial empty user settings and save
  if (jQuery.cookie("usrSets") != null) {
    var usrSets = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.cookie("usrSets"))
  } else { 
    var usrSets = {};
    jQuery.cookie("usrSets", JSON.stringify(usrSets));
  }

  jQuery.each(defSets, function(key, value){
    // check every default setting
    if (usrSets[key] != undefined) {
  // if a user setting exists for respective default setting use that
      var key = usrSets[key];
      // uval = usrSets[key];
      // dval = defSets[key];
      // console.log("User have a setting for -" + key + "- So the value (" + uval + ") will be used instead of default: " + dval);
} else {
      var key = defSets[key];
      // console.log ("No user setting for -" + key + "- will use default val of :" + dval);
};
});
```

after these, ideally, i'd be able to use those var's anywhere below these lines,
assuming var ratio has been already created from above; i could `jQuery(".selector").height(jQuery(this).width * ratio);`

Comment: Whitespace. Please use more of it.

Comment: You use `!=` where you likely meant `!==`

Comment: You don't cache the return value of `jQuery.cookie`. Perhaps you should, if only for "code style".

Answer (score 0):

If storing some info globally is what you need I'dd use [namespaces](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/). I think this is better, but after all that is a matter of preference, I guess